# Initialize a bean depends on another bean's property

Tags: spring

In Spring, I want to load a bean based on another bean's property.
How can I create another bean based on Bean A's enable value?

```
@bean (name=A) Class A{ int enabled = true }
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest in cleanest way is to instantiate the second bean within an configuration class - see below.

```
@Configuration
public BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    @Autowirde
    B b(A a) {
        if (a.enabled) return BEnabledBean();
        return BDisabledBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have many beans dependent on enum values, how do I choose one to create? Long if-else?